# Neo4j match by user defined variable

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

I match, based on ident:

> create (lpam:Isbn{ident:"La physique avec Maple",name:"La physique avec Maple",type:"isbn",isbnValue:"2-7298-7948-X",isbnCanonique:"",sumUp:"Physique, Chimie, Fractales et Chaos"});
> create (p138:Page{ident:"La physique avec Maplep138",name:"p138",,type:"page"});
> MATCH (a), (b) WHERE  a.ident = "La physique avec Maple" AND b.ident = "La physique avec Maplep138" CREATE (a)-[r:CONTAINS]->(b) RETURN r.

ident strings are too long, whereas lpam p138 are shorter, best for me.
1)Can't I match based on the node variable lpam  ? something like

> MATCH (a), (b) WHERE var(a) = "lpam" AND b.ident = "La physique avec
> Maplep138" CREATE (a)-[r:CONTAINS]->(b) RETURN r

2. 

> create (p138:Page.....

What is the role of the variable (p138) if I can not match it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `match` again for creating relationships. You can use the variables directly to create relationships like:

```
CREATE (lpam:Isbn{ident:"La physique avec Maple",name:"La physique avec Maple",type:"isbn",isbnValue:"2-7298-7948-X",isbnCanonique:"",sumUp:"Physique, Chimie, Fractales et Chaos"});
CREATE (p138:Page{ident:"La physique avec Maplep138",name:"p138",,type:"page"});
CREATE (lpam)-[r:CONTAINS]->(p138) RETURN r;
```